# Tell to linux binary not load specific shared libraries

Tags: linux, dependencies, shared-library

I have a problem with shared libraries, Command show warning each time when it run's,

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xxxx.so'`

whereas it run fine with not issues, i want to remove `libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found` this line from list so that it will not look for this shared library.

```
ldd ...php/ext/curl.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe1a65f000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fb9fdd8f000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fb9fdb1f000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb9fd751000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fb9fd4c0000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fb9fcff7000)
        libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fb9fcdb5000)
        liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fb9fcba8000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb9fc990000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb9fc774000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb9fc570000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb9fe22e000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fb9fc356000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

what to do ?

Comment: ... Just what did you do to that system that `libcrypto.so` is missing in the first place? I get the feeling that something *else* went badly wrong and your question will only (and poorly) address the symptom rather than the actual cause.

Answer (score 1):

Recompile php entirely from without the SSL crypto library.

This may, depending on the situation, include *rewriting* chunks of the code to remove any references that call functions provided by said library.

Alternately: Install `libssl` as Alex suggests. How *did* you manage, in this day and age, to install php without installing all its correct dependencies at the same time anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Install the libssl1.0 and libssl-dev package. You cannot just remove a required library from a binary. For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
```